# std::map.operator[] not working with global maps

Tags: c++, c++11, maps

Can someone tell me how I can make use of `std::map.operator[]` to get the value of a `const std::map` ?

For example:

file.h

```cpp
#ifndef _FILE_H
#define _FILE_H
#include <map>
#include <string>
const std::map<std::string,std::string> STRINGS= {
    {"COMPANY","MyCo"}
    ,{"YEAR","2022"}
};
#endif
```

file.cpp

```cpp
#include "cpp_playground.h"
#include <iostream>
int main (void){
    std::cout<< "Code by "<< STRINGS["COMPANY"] << " " << STRINGS["YEAR"] << std::endl;
}
```

With Visual Studio 2015 I get this error, but I can't interpret it

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2678   binary '[': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::map<std::string,std::string,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    cpp_playground  d:\user\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\cpp_playground\cpp_playground.cpp 10
```

Comment: `std::map` does not have a `operator[](...) const`, only a non-`const` version. So, you cannot use `[]` on a `const map`, remove the `const` and it works: https://godbolt.org/z/9MzPEY7dW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `operator[]` in `std::map` is defined to return a reference to the object with the given key - or create it, if it doesn't exist, which modifies the map, that's why it's not a const method. There is no const version of that operator, that's why you get the shown error.

Use [`std::map`'s `at(...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) function for access-only. **Note that it throws a `std::out_of_range` exception** if the given key is not contained in the map; in C++20 or later you can use [`contains()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/contains) to check whether the given key exists.

Comment: For the future: <https://wg21.link/p2568>